# JSF - Change panelGroup by using ajax calls - Beans, EL and?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, javabeans

I have to make a sort of switch of some `panelGroup` UI. 
About the view section, i made this :

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="profile_content">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="content_title">
        Profilo Utente
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{selector.profile_page=='main'}">
        <ui:include src="/profile/profile_main.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{selector.profile_page=='edit'}">
        <ui:include src="/profile/profile_edit.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{selector.profile_page=='insert'}">
        <ui:include src="/profile/profile_articles.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Now, to change this value, i written an exclusive JavaBean, called Selector :

```
@ManagedBean(name="selector")
@RequestScoped
public class Selector {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.profile_page}")
    private String profile_page;

    public String getProfile_page() {
        if(profile_page==null || profile_page.trim().isEmpty()) {
            this.profile_page="main";
        }
        return profile_page;
    }
    public void setProfile_page(String profile_page) { this.profile_page=profile_page; }
}
```

So, right now succeeds my problem : when i change the "context" by using some `h:commandButton`, i'd like to use asynch call to the server. This is my Button Panel :

```
<h:commandButton value="EDIT">
    <f:ajax event="action" execute="???" render=":profile_content"/>
</h:commandButton>

<h:commandButton value="PM">
    <f:ajax event="action" execute="???" render=":profile_content"/>
</h:commandButton>

<h:commandButton value="ARTICLES">
    <f:ajax event="action" execute="???" render=":profile_content"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

I don't know what to put on `execute`, so that i edit the Beans value and i change the context by using `render=":profile_content"`

Hope this question is comprehendible. Forgive me about language :)

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`f:setPropertyActionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/setPropertyActionListener.html). You don't need to override the default of [`f:ajax`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html)'s `execute` attribute (which is `@this`, the sole button).

E.g.

```
<h:commandButton value="EDIT">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{selector.profile_page}" value="edit" />
    <f:ajax event="action" render=":profile_content"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Note that the [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) recommends CamelCase over under_score. I'd suggest to fix `profile_page` to be `profilePage`. This is Java, not PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about CamelCase. Yeah, this works. That I find strange, is that if I remove <f:ajax>, it do a normal request to the server (page is reloaded). Else, if I add <f:ajax>, the previous ActionListener work as asynch. Strange behaviour, i need to learn why this happens :)

Comment: That's the whole point of `f:ajax`. To change it to async (ajaxical) submit.

Comment: You are a really expert of JSF!! As said many times, Thanks again man! I think you deserve 1-10 beers :)

Comment: Why have you got a colon : before profile_content i.e  <f:ajax event="action" render=":profile_content"/> should not it be with out colon I was after this too but I did not need colon infact colon will throw an error that id::profile_content not found. needless to say have already upvoted answer and coments. please reply if you can cheers.

Comment: @Shahzeb: That's just what the OP used. It is mandatory when the component is not inside the same form. If you have a problem/question, just press the `Ask Question` button.